# Error when trying to add system:time_start when using reduceRegions in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, datetime, reducers

I am reducing an image collection into a feature collection by using a function to map the `reduceRegions` function to each image in a collection. I'm trying to make sure the `system:time_start property` is carried over. My code is below

```
var DHW_region = DHW.map(function(image){
  return image
  .reduceRegions({
  collection:reefsEdit , 
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale: 30
 })
  .set(ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')));
 });

 DHW_region = DHW_region.flatten();
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and I'm getting an error

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=0): Dictionary: Unrecognized arguments to Dictionary constructor.
```

Where am I going wrong with this? Link to my code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjw1280%2FReef_Stress_Exposure%3ADATE_LIST_TEST_DHW%20(copy))

Comment: you should share the collections (`DHW_region` and `reefsEdit`) or make proxy ones so we can reproduce the error

Comment: Thanks I have added a link to my code. Line 164. Run the code and you should see the error. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `.set()` should be as follows (see docs):

> **var_args (VarArgs):** Either a dictionary of properties, or a vararg sequence of properties, e.g. key1, value1, key2, value2, ..

In your code, you set an `ee.Date()` as argument for `.set()`. You should 1) make a a vararg sequence of properties or 2) make a dictionary of properties:

```
.set('system:time_start',image.date())

.set({'system:time_start',: image.date()})
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1cd148362d404e739d31a0c6322deae)

Comment: ah OK thanks, that stops the error